# how to Create multiple json object & post in single request

Tags: json, jmeter

I have my csv file as:

[row 1 - 1000 uuids & row2 - 1000 names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Is3.png)

i need to call each uuid & their corresponding name in below json structure and finally need to post in single request.

so far i have tried below json in jsr223 preprocessor & response is successful:

```
      import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
      def builder = new JsonBuilder()

      builder({
      Data{
      "${__UUID()}"{
         name{
            "${__RandomString(10,abcdefg)}"(1)
         }
         p([1,1])
         m([1,2])
         o([2,3])
       }
     }
     E([])
     S(${__time()})
     })
     println builder.toPrettyString()
     vars.put("json", builder.toPrettyString());
```

Now the problem is i need to link line 6 ("${__UUID()}) & line 8  (${__RandomString(10,abcdefg)}) with csv file & need to call all the columns, which i haven't known how to proceed & finally post as single request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the arbitrary cell from the CSV file using [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), check out [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime/) article for more details.

Not knowing the format of the JSON payload you're trying to generate it is not possible to come up with the comprehensive solution, but one thing is obvious, as per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

So **don't ever inline** [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into JSR223 scripts as you do because it will update only once, on subsequent iterations the value will be cached and will not update.